# NDR message forward to recipient

Tags: exchange-2010

When an external user emails someone in my exchange server. An NDR or DSN is created if the total size of email/attachment exceeds the limit. We don't permit postmaster messages to escape our system and return to sender. BUT, how can I alert the recipient in my exchange that this happened? Currently neither the sender or the receiver knows that the message was dropped because of too-large email size. How can i get some automatic notification that this happened? BTW,I'm usind Exchange Server 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the Set-TransportConfig cmdlet to set the *GenerateCopyOfDSNFor* value for any DSNs you want to monitor (some are there by default), and Set-OrganizationConfig *MicrosoftExchangeRecipientReplyRecipient* value to a mailbox that should receive Exchange messages (discarded by default/not set).

See Set-TransportConfig: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124151(v=exchg.141).aspx

See Set-OrganizationConfig: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997443(v=exchg.141).aspx

Here's a guide that goes over the process for 2007, which is similar: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb400930(v=exchg.80).aspx